# Django unexpected keyword argument "encoder"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I am using django to create a back-end for my web app and I am getting an Exception Type: TypeError at /register/
Exception Value: Field.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoder'.
Meanwhile there's no field like that in my views.py or serializers.py.

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
    from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
    from django.core.mail import send_mail
    from django.http import JsonResponse
    from rest_framework.generics import UpdateAPIView
    from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
    from .serializers import UserProfileSerializer, ProfileViewSerializer, FavoriteSerializer, MessageSerializer
    from django.db.models import Q
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, get_user_model, login
    from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes
    from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode, urlsafe_base64_decode
    from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
    from rest_framework import generics, permissions, serializers, status
    from rest_framework.response import Response
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.http import JsonResponse
    from rest_framework.views import APIView
    from .models import Favorite, ProfileView, UserProfile, Message
    from random import randint
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
    from .serializers import (
        LoginSerializer,
        UserProfileSerializer,
        ProfileViewSerializer,
        FavoriteSerializer,
    )
    
    
    email_domain = (
        ("ucc.edu.gh", "University of Cape Coast"),
        ("knust.edu.gh", "Kwame Nkrumah University of Science and Technology"),
        ("ug.edu.gh", "University of Ghana"),
        ("uew.edu.gh", "University of Education, Winneba"),
        ("umat.edu.gh", "University of Mines and Technology"),
        ("uds.edu.gh", "University of Development Studies"),
        ("upsa.edu.gh", "University of Professional Studies, Accra"),
        ("uenr.edu.gh", "University of Energy and Natural Resources"),
        ("uhas.edu.gh", "University of Health and Allied Sciences"),
        ("gimpa.edu.gh", "Ghana Institute of Management and Public Administration"),
        ("atu.edu.gh", "Accra Technical University"),
        ("ashesi.edu.gh", "Ashesi University"),
        ("central.edu.gh", "Central University"),
        ("kstu.edu.gh", "Kumasi Technical University"),
    )
    
    
    User = get_user_model()
    
    
    class RegisterView(APIView):
    
        def post(self, request, format=None):
            serializer = UserProfileSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                user = serializer.save()
    
                # Generate a random one-time password
                otp = randint(100000, 999999)
                # Save the one-time password in the session
                request.session["otp"] = otp
                request.session["email"] = user.email
                # Send the one-time password to the user's email
                send_mail(
                    "AlmaMingle Account Verification",
                    f"Hello {user}, \nVerify your account to login.  \nYour one-time password is {otp}",
                    settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                    [user.email],
                    fail_silently=False,
                )
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            else:
                return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    
    
    class VerifyEmailView(APIView):
        def post(self, request):
            otp = request.data.get("otp")
            email = request.session.get("email")
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(email=email)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                return Response(
                    {"error": "User does not exist"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
                )
            if otp == request.session.get("otp"):
                # Activate the user's account
                user.is_active = True
                user.save()
                # Log the user in
                user = authenticate(request, email=email)
                login(request, user)
                serializer = UserProfileSerializer(user.userprofile)
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                return Response(
                    {"error": "Invalid OTP"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
                )
    
    
    class LoginView(APIView):
        def post(self, request, format=None):
            serializer = LoginSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                user = serializer.validated_data["user"]
                login(request, user)
                return Response({"message": "Successfully logged in"})
            else:
                return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)
    
    
    class CustomPasswordResetSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        email = serializers.EmailField()
    
        def validate_email(self, email):
            # Check if the email exists in the database
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(email=email)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                raise serializers.ValidationError(
                    "User with this email does not exist.")
            return email
    
        def save(self):
            # Get the user and generate the password reset token
            user = User.objects.get(email=self.validated_data["email"])
            token = urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk))
            # Send the password reset email
            subject = _("Password reset")
            message = _(
                "Please click on the following link to reset your password:\n\n"
                "http://localhost:8000/reset-password/{token}/"
            )
            message = message.format(token=token)
            send_mail(subject, message, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [user.email])
    
    
    class CustomChangePasswordSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        new_password = serializers.CharField(max_length=128)
        token = serializers.CharField()
    
        def validate_token(self, token):
            # Check if the token is valid
            try:
                uid = urlsafe_base64_decode(token).decode()
                self.user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
            except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
                raise serializers.ValidationError("Invalid token.")
            return token
    
        def save(self):
            # Set the new password for the user
            self.user.set_password(self.validated_data["new_password"])
            self.user.save()
    
    
    class CustomPasswordResetView(generics.GenericAPIView):
        serializer_class = CustomPasswordResetSerializer
    
        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save()
            return Response({"detail": "Password reset email has been sent."})
    
    
    class CustomChangePasswordView(generics.GenericAPIView):
        serializer_class = CustomChangePasswordSerializer
        
    
        def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save()
            return Response({"detail": "Password has been reset."})
    
    
    @login_required
    def delete_account(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            password = request.POST.get("password")
            if request.user.check_password(password):
                # Password confirmation successful, proceed with deletion
                request.user.delete()
                return JsonResponse({"success": True})
            else:
                # Incorrect password, return an error response
                return JsonResponse({"success": False, "error": "Incorrect password."})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({"success": False, "error": "Invalid request method."})
    
    
    class UserProfileView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
        serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
        permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    
        def get_queryset(self):
            user = self.request.user
            return UserProfile.objects.filter(user=user)
    
    
    class ProfileViewList(generics.ListAPIView):
        serializer_class = ProfileViewSerializer
        permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    
        def get_queryset(self):
            user = self.request.user
            return ProfileView.objects.filter(viewed_by=user)
    
    
    class FavoriteList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
        serializer_class = FavoriteSerializer
        permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    
        def get_queryset(self):
            user = self.request.user
            return Favorite.objects.filter(user=user)
    
    
    class FavoriteDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
        serializer_class = FavoriteSerializer
        permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    
        def get_queryset(self):
            user = self.request.user
            return Favorite.objects.filter(user=user)
    
    
    class MessageListView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateAPIView):
        serializer_class = MessageSerializer
        permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    
        def get(self, request):
            messages = Message.objects.filter(
                Q(sender=request.user) | Q(recipient=request.user)
            ).order_by("-timestamp")
            serializer = self.serializer_class(messages, many=True)
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from .models import Favorite, ProfileView, UserProfile, Message
    from rest_framework.authentication import authenticate
    from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
    
    
    class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = UserProfile
            fields = (
                "id",
                "username",
                "email",
                "profile_picture",
                "age",
                "university_name",
                "basic_information",
                "passions",
                "about_section",
            )
            extra_kwargs = {
                "profile_picture": {"required": False},
                "age": {"required": False},
                "university_name": {"required": False},
                "basic_information": {"required": False},
                "passions": {"required": False},
                "about_section": {"required": False},
            }
    
        def create(self, validated_data):
            username = validated_data.pop("username")
            password = validated_data.pop("password")
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
            profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=user, **validated_data)
            return profile
    
        def update(self, instance, validated_data):
            user_data = validated_data.pop("user", {})
            password = user_data.get("password")
            instance = super().update(instance, validated_data)
            if password:
                instance.user.set_password(password)
                instance.user.save()
            return instance
    
        @staticmethod
        def setup_eager_loading(queryset):
            queryset = queryset.select_related("user")
            return queryset
    
    
    class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        username = serializers.CharField()
        password = serializers.CharField()
    
        def validate(self, data):
            user = authenticate(**data)
            if user:
                data["user"] = user
                return data
            else:
                raise serializers.ValidationError("Invalid username or password")
    
    
    class FavoriteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Favorite
            fields = ("id", "user", "favorite_user", "timestamp")
    
    
    class ProfileViewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = ProfileView
            fields = ("id", "viewer", "viewed_user", "timestamp")
    
    
    class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        auth_token = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ("id", "username", "email", "auth_token")
            read_only_fields = ("id", "username", "email")
    
        def get_auth_token(self, obj):
            token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=obj)
            return token.key
    
    class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        sender = UserSerializer()
        recipient = UserSerializer()
    
        class Meta:
            model = Message
            fields = '__all__'
```

Please any help?

I have deleted all the project and started again, when I use postman, I get a CSRFToken error whiles I am not using CSRFToken as my authentication type and when I use django's localhost to try, I get unexpected keyword argument 'encoder'.

Comment: Share the full traceback.

Comment: TypeError at /register/

Field.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoder'

Request Method:  POST
Request URL:  http://localhost:8000/register/
Django Version:  4.2.2
Exception Type:  TypeError
Exception Value:  

Field.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoder'

Exception Location:  /home/cyb3r/Project/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py, line 1374, in __init__
Raised during:  accounts.views.RegisterView
Python Executable:  /home/cyb3r/Project/env/bin/python
Python Version:  3.11.2